# Resizing of navbarPage() title and tab names in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

First, here's the skeleton code of the UI for the app I am working on:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

player.list <- c('Steph', 'LeBron', 'Kyrie')
names(player.list) <- player.list

ui <- shinyUI(
        navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("united"), h1(style="text-align:center", "Interactive NBA Graphing & Charting Application"),

                   # first tab
                   tabPanel(h3("Shot Charts"), sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                       selectInput("name", "Select Player", choices = player.list, selected = 'Steph'),

                       br(), br(), br(), br(),
                       h5("Author"),
                       a(h5("Nicholas Canova"), href="https://twitter.com/SmokeyCanova")
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                       h4("Shot Chart of Player"),
                       plotOutput('shotchart')
                     )
                   )),

                   # second tab
                   tabPanel(h3("Shot Type Analysis for Two Seasons"), sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                       selectInput("name", "Select Player", choices = player.list, selected = 'Steph'),

                       br(), br(), br(), br(),
                       h5("Author"),
                       a(h5("Nicholas Canova"), href="https://twitter.com/SmokeyCanova"),
                       p("Draw your own plot?"),

                       downloadButton('downloadChart', 'Download (csv File)')
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                       h4("Fast Fact"),
                       plotOutput('playerchart')
                     )
                   )),

                   # third tab
                   tabPanel(h3("Assist Networks"), sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                       selectInput("name", "Select Player", choices = player.list, selected = 'Steph'),

                       br(), br(), br(), br(),
                       h5("Author"),
                       a(h5("Nicholas Canova"), href="https://twitter.com/SmokeyCanova")
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                       h4("Shot Chart of Player"),
                       plotOutput('shotchart')
                     )
                   )),

                   # fourth tab
                   tabPanel(h3("Game Recaps"), sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                       selectInput("name", "Select Player", choices = player.list, selected = 'Steph'),

                       br(), br(), br(), br(),
                       h5("Author"),
                       a(h5("Nicholas Canova"), href="https://twitter.com/SmokeyCanova")
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                       h4("Shot Chart of Player"),
                       plotOutput('shotchart')
                     )
                   ))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$shotchart <- renderPlot({  
    mydf <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
    ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
  })

  output$playerchart <- renderPlot({
    mydf <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = c(5,4,3,2,1))
    ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

At full screen, the navbar title and tab names looks fine:

[image]
When i shrink the width of my window, it looks bad:

[image]
When I shrink the window further, to the point that the main title itself wraps, it looks even worse:

[image]

Any thoughts on how I can improve this? I don't generally use navbarPage for my shiny apps, however for the app I am working on, I'd like the tab functionality, with each tab having its own set of inputs in the tab panel. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT : I'd like to keep the header tags, if possible, although those seem to be what's causing the problem...

EDIT2: I think i can fix this problem if I can simply resize the text without having to use header tags, but not sure how to do that.

EDIT3: i think, to do edit2, i need to learn more about how to use tags to manipulate the css to make the page look how i'd like. any help with that also appreciated!